# Prove $\int 1-\prod_{i=1}^n (1- \mathbb{I}_{A_i}) d \mu= \mu ( \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i )$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measurable space. $A_1, A_2,...,A_n \in \mathcal{A}$ are sets with finite measure. 
I have to prove $\int 1-\prod_{i=1}^n (1- \mathbb{I}_{A_i}) d \mu= \mu ( \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i )$. But I am once again totaly puzzeld how to start.

---

**Result**:

I solved the problem, using the hint by Weltschmerz. By now I found an elegant way of the prove, which simply is
$$\int 1 - \prod_{i=1}^n \left( 1- \mathbb{I}_{A_i} \right) d \mu= \int 1 - \prod_{i=1}^n \left( \mathbb{I}_{A_i^C} \right) d \mu$$ $$ = \int 1 - \mathbb{I}_{\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i^C} d \mu = \int \mathbb{I}_{\left( \bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i^C \right)^C} d \mu = \int \mathbb{I}_{\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i} d \mu= \mu \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \right)$$

Comment: I suggest you begin by looking at where the integrand is (or not) $0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Giveaway hint: $1-\prod_{i=1}^n (1-\mathbb{I}_{A_i})$ is $1$ if $x\in$ ... and $0$ if $x\in$ ..., and that $=\mathbb{I}_{\textrm{something}}$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got the idea!